Variable selection in models with pseudo-observations (survival analysis)
I need to use pseudo-observations for a survival study. Therefore, I am using the eventglm package in R with the functions cumincglm and rmeanglm.
In my dataset, I have many variables, and I would like to perform variable selection for these types of models (cumincglm and rmeanglm). Is it possible to do variable selection using the commands we use for classic GLMs, such as step() or dropterm()? If not, how can I perform variable selection?

I think that the consensus on this site would be that you shouldn't do variable selection in those ways at all. See this page, for example. Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies covers more reliable ways to develop regression models of all kinds; Chapter 4 and its discussion of "data reduction" (Section 4.7) might be particularly relevant to your study.
